# Using CSS3 on IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css, cross-browser

Anyone know of a script that would give CSS3 support to IE 7 please?

Thanks

Comment: Fail. (Epic Fail.) (Of course I'm kidding, mostly.)

Comment: Why the vote down? Anything wrong with my question?

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't down vote you (just thought it was funny).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try: http://css3pie.com/